# Bubble Sort logical error VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

This program suppose to sort records(in arySort) in ascending order by last name(index 1 in aryTemp and aryTemp2) and place the result in the list box over the old, preloaded, unsorted records.

It sorts them strangely, I have to click multiple times the Ascending button to get the actual sort result that I suppose to get from clicking the button once.

*Why doesn't it sort items with a single mouse click?*

The source:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "Students.txt"
    Dim numberOfRecords As Integer 'total number of records
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
            Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)
            Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
                lstBox.Items.Add(objReader.ReadLine)
                numberOfRecords += 1
            Loop
            objReader.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAscending_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAscending.Click
        'load all students into array
        Dim arySort(numberOfRecords - 1) As String
        Dim aryTemp() As String 'holds first record's last name
        Dim aryTemp2() As String 'holds second record's last name
        For i = 0 To numberOfRecords - 1
            arySort(i) = lstBox.Items(i)
        Next
        Dim temp As String 'holds temporary record
        Dim k As Integer
        For i = 0 To arySort.Length - 2
            aryTemp = Split(arySort(i), " ")
            For k = i + 1 To arySort.Length - 1
                aryTemp2 = Split(arySort(k), " ")
                If aryTemp(1) < aryTemp2(1) Then
                    temp = arySort(k)
                    arySort(k) = arySort(i)
                    arySort(i) = temp
                End If
            Next
        Next
        lstBox.Items.Clear()
        numberOfRecords = 0
        For i = 0 To arySort.Length - 1
            lstBox.Items.Add(arySort(i))
            numberOfRecords += 1
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Nice description, but this is a Q&A site and I am afraid that you forgot to ask a question here.

Comment: I'm afraid not many people will go through the hassle of downloading your project. I recommend that you post your algorithm here: Use the "edit" link below your question; then use the "code sample" button to format your code. Please only post *relevant* parts of the algorithm here, i.e., make your code as small as possible, but as long as necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Okay. The entire program is just a list box and a button.

Comment: Assuming this is homework. You might want to add a homework tag. If it isn't homework you shouldn't be rolling your own bubble sort.

Comment: It's not my bubble sort, I'm just using bubble sort's algorithm as a template for my needs to sort a list of records ascending determined by the last name.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to sort your list (as you say in the comment), *don't* implement your own sort mechanism but use the one of .NET:

```
' Define how we want to compare items '
Function compareByLastName(ByVal item1 As String, ByVal item2 As String) As Integer
    Return String.Compare(item1.Split(" ")(1), item2.Split(" ")(1))
End Function

Private Sub btnAscending_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAscending.Click
    ' load all students into array '
    Dim arySort(numberOfRecords - 1) As String
    For i = 0 To numberOfRecords - 1
        arySort(i) = lstBox.Items(i)
    Next

    ' Use built-in .NET magic '
    Array.Sort(arySort, AddressOf compareByLastName)

    ' Write the values back into your list box '
    lstBox.Items.Clear()
    numberOfRecords = 0
    For i = 0 To arySort.Length - 1
        lstBox.Items.Add(arySort(i))
        numberOfRecords += 1
    Next
End Sub
```

This uses the built-in quicksort algorithm of the .NET class library. Here's the documentation of the method we are using: [Array.Sort(T(), Comparison(Of T))](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxt053xf.aspx).

Comment: @JohnnyCake: So you *should* add the homework tag to your question. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

compare with my working bubble sort:

```
Public Sub BubbleSort(ByVal arr() As Integer)
    Dim flag As Boolean = False
    For i As Integer = 0 To arr.Length - 1
        For j As Integer = 0 To arr.Length - 2 - i
            If arr(j + 1) < arr(j) Then
                flag = True
                Dim temp As Integer = arr(j)
                arr(j) = arr(j + 1)
                arr(j + 1) = temp
            End If
        Next
        If flag = False Then Return ' no swaps =>already sorted
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You're comparing an entire record string which happens to be a single element from my arySort. But each record from my arySort, according to bubble sort, are segmented into aryTemp and aryTemp2. I have to compare only the last names which are placed inside the aryTemp and aryTemp2's for comparison under index 1.

Comment: @JohnnyCake: So what? The algorithm is the same, just the comparison needs to be adjusted, i.e., you just replace `arr(j)` with `Split(arySort(j), " ")(1)`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I see a two major issues with your algorithm:

- It's not bubble sort. [Bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_Sort) swaps *adjacent* elements, i.e., it swaps i with i+1. You, on the other hand, swap some element i with the first j > i where name(i) < name(j). Maybe you should show us, in pseudo code, which algorithm you are actually trying to implement?
- `aryTemp` contains element i and `aryTemp2` contains some element j > i. Why do you swap the elements if `aryTemp(1) < aryTemp2(1)`? Isn't that already the *correct* order if you want your elements to be sorted ascending?

Comment: If last name in aryTemp is less than last name in aryTemp2 then move the first record down.

Comment: @Johnny: Why? *Ascending* means that the *lesser* name (= the one earlier in the alphabet) is further *up*, not *down*.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the sorting(maybe I confused ascending with descending) but it just that I have to press the Ascending button many times until the list box stops changing the positions of items and then looks sorted. That's why I had a link to an actual project instead of source before.

Comment: @Johnny: Ok. Still, my main point is that what you are implementing is *not* bubble sort and that this might be the reason why your algorithm doesn't work.